# useFocusEffect runs every time useState updates

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit, react-navigation-v6

I've been trying to use `useState` inside `useFocusEffect`. Following react-navigation I got something like this:

```
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      console.log(counter);
    }, [counter]),
  );
```

Now the problem is that every time `counter` updates, `useFocusEffect` fires. What I want is for it to fire only when screen comes into focus. Now I've also tried doing this with navigation focus listener:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onFocus = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      console.log(counter);
    });

    return onFocus;
  }, [navigation, counter]);
```

It works, well partially. While the `onFocus` function is performed only when screen comes into focus, `useEffect` fires every time counter updates. Same thing happens when using redux-toolkit slices. How can I prevent this behaviour?

---

### Update

I should add that removing `counter` from dependency array prevents it from updating in subsequential runs. So I will rephrase the question. Is there a way to either fix `useCallback` by preventing it from firing every time `counter` updates or fix `useEffect` so that it fires only on focus with `counter` updated?

Answer (score 0):

You included `counter` in the dependency array of your useEffect.  This tells the useEffect to run every time a change is made to `counter`.  See the docs for useEffect here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `useEffect` to this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    console.log(counter);
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]); // remove `counter` from your dependency array
```

The problem you had was your `counter` value was in the dependency array of your `useEffect` dependency array. This means that every time your `counter` value changes the callback inside your `useEffect` will run which is obviously undesirable.

You most likely followed CRA's default linting rules where they give you a warning to add items to the dependency array, I'd highly recommend turning that off in your linting rules.

Comment: Right forgot to add that one to the question. That won't work as the value of useState (counter in this case) won't update in subsequential activations of listener callback. So if I update value go to different screen and come back it will still be the same value as the first time.

Comment: Then you’ll need to move your state (and effect hook) to a higher level in your app.

Comment: The useEffect callback is adding an event Listener, but why is the focus event firing everytime though?